# JMeter - Duration set, but all the request matters?

Tags: jmeter

I have 1 thread group with 5 calls - running on 1 thread and Infinite loop count of the thread. The thread group has set "Duration" to 1 minute. I want the test to complete in approximately 1 minute, but it's fine with me too even if it ends 10 seconds later. The main question is how to make sure that all requests from the current thread group loop are executed before it ends. With this configuration nothing doesn't mattter, it just stop on the 60 secs. I want to make sure for example, that if we are in the middle of those 5 request, let's say 5 full loops are completed (25 requests), but on the 6th - just 2 requests are completed on the 60 sec, it should complete the remaining 3 requests and then it will be unable to stop the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting an endless loop on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level put your requests under the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter) instead.

You can use the following [__groovy function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as the condition:

```
${__groovy((System.currentTimeMillis() - (vars.get('TESTSTART.MS') as long)) < 60000,)}
```

[image]

This will guarantee that:

1. Your test will last at least 1 minute
2. All While Controller children will be executed fully

Comment: Thank you so much, Dmitry T, as usual - very helpful! Tried that and it works exactly in the way I want!